# Creating a yarn dependency resolution for an alias

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json

In `package.json` I have

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-redux8": "npm:react-redux@^8.0",
    ...
  }
```

in my code I'm trying to include

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
```

but I get errors during build with eg.

```bash
ERROR in ./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/rtk-query-react.esm.js 496:31-41
"export 'useStore' (imported as 'rrUseStore') was not found in 'react-redux'
```

I've tried to handle this in the `resolutions` block using all of the following

```json
"**/@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "8.1.3",
"**/@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "^8.0",
"**/@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "npm:react-redux@^8.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "8.1.3",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "^8.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/react-redux": "npm:react-redux@^8.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/**/react-redux": "8.1.3",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/**/react-redux": "^8.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit/**/react-redux": "npm:react-redux@^8.0",
```

none of which resolve the issue. Using `overrides` isn't an option since I'm using `yarn` and not `npm`.

Can `yarn` and `resolutions` be used for what I'm trying to do? I thought that was the point of `resolutions`.